# form inside a foreach loop wont POST

Tags: php, forms, foreach

For what ever reason I just cant seem to work this out, I know I've solved this before but can't remember how. I have a set of data in a database. I use a `foreach` to pull each row from the database so I can edit them.

Then in the `foreach` tag I have a form with the data set out so I can edit it and once I'm done I can click edit and the idea is the form for that specific set of data would go through the function and edit data on the row where `id = $id` ...

Like I said I've solved this issue before but for the life of me I cant work out what to do this time round. Can anyone suggest anything, I've not posted any code as I don't know if it's needed, it seems simple, a form and how to get it to send individual forms from within a `foreach` loop, but I can provide code if needed.

The form within the foreach

```
$marquee = live_news_for_marquee($headline, $type);
foreach ($marquee as $headline) {
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <td><input name="id" type="text" class="" style="width:10px;" value="<?php echo $headline['id']; ?>" disabled="disabled"></td>
    <td><textarea name="update_headline" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $headline['headline']; ?></textarea></td>
    <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $headline['date']); ?></td>
    <td>
        <select name="update_type" id="">
            <option value="<?php echo $headline['type']; ?>"><?php echo $headline['type']; ?></option>
            <option value="BreakingNews">Breaking News</option>
            <option value="Standard">Standard News</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td><input type="checkbox" name="live" value="1" <?php if ($headline['live'] == 1) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>>Live <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="live" value="0" <?php if ($headline['live'] == 0) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>>Off </td>
    <td><button class="btn red_btn">Edit</button></td>
</form>
<?php
;}
?>
```

Here is more code that is associated with the code already provided.. this first code is from the top of the page, where i process the POST info.. I have messed around with it plenty of times because the info just didn't seem to POST so i couldn't do anything at all..

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['update_headline']) && isset($_POST['update_type']) && isset($_POST['live'])) {
$errors = array();

$update_id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$update_headline = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update_headline']);
$update_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update_type']);
$live = (int)$_POST['live'];

if (empty($update_id)) {
    $errors[] = 'Theres something that went wrong!';
}
if (empty($update_headline)) {
    $errors[] = 'You need a headline before you send this!';
}
if (empty($update_type)) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to give this entry a "type of entry"!';
}
if (empty($live)) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to select if this headline will be live on the site, or not and stored in the db!';
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
} else {
    edit_news($update_id, $update_headline, $update_type, $live);
    ?>
<br><br>
        <div class="success_msg"><p>The Headline News has been modified successfully.</p></div> 
    <?php
}

}
```

Comment: Why not use one form and an arrays for the field names?

Comment: I may be missing something, but where is the "Submit" button?

Comment: there is a button-Edit but I just left it as <button class="btn red_btn"></button> I changed it for an input type submit and nothing changed

Comment: this may not be anything but looking at the code and as it is colour differently, if you take a look at the button I put in the code, look just after where it sasy "Edit" and to the right, the closing button tag is one colour, to start with, its a different colour than the opening tag, and the closing </td> tag is 2 different colours itself, could this have anything to do why things just not seem to be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a new button using this exact format:

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

Also be sure to include the quotes. It won't work without them.

Comment: somehow when i just took out the button saved it put a new one back in it all started working correctly, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<button>` to a `<submit>` or `<input type=submit>`. `<button>` won't trigger submission when clicked.

Comment: i swapped out the button, and placed an input type submit in its place but that didn't make a difference..im going to post all the code that is associated with this and someone maybe able to tell me where my mistake is and how/why i made it

Comment: Just to clarify, does anything happen at all when you click the button?